# Поиск RFC на транспортном уровне по номеру порта(tcp/udp)

Tags: сеть, tcp, udp, протоколы, rfc

Преподаватель задал сформировать таблицу с описанием определённых портов,как источник скинул документ 1992 подобный таблице но RFC там почти не прописано относительно протоколов,используя гугл я кое как смог выгуглить несколько RFC но не более,поэтому прошу вашей помощи.

Порты:
16
46
76
106
136
166
196
226
256
286
316
346
376
406
436
466
496
526
556
586
616
646
676
706
736
766
796
826
856
886
916
946
976
1006

Буду благодарен как за ответ так и за подсказку как их искать

Comment: Вот полная таблица со ссылками на RFC https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml

Comment: Преподаватель скидывал нам этот же файл но сказал что РФС должен быть у каждого протокола а в этом документе он есть условно у 20% протоколов

Comment: Значит преподаватель вас обманывает, RFC вовсе не должен быть у каждого протокола

Comment: спасибо за информацию